# Sass won't compile SCSS (EACCES error)

Tags: sass, compilation, rubygems

I'm trying to compile my SCSS file but I always get this error. This is new because before the Windows 10 Creator Update it was working fine.

**Here's the error :**

```
$ sass --no-cache --update --trace app.scss:app.css
    c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:516:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - appp.css (Errno::EACCES)
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:516:in `open'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:516:in `write_file'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:503:in `update_stylesheet'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in `block in update_stylesheets'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/plugin.rb:82:in `update_stylesheets'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:340:in `watch_or_update'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in `process_result'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/bin/sass:23:in `load'
            from c:/Ruby24-x64/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

I checked where the compiler fail and this is what I got :

```
513    def write_file(fileName, content)
514      flag = 'w'
515      flag = 'wb' if Sass::Util.windows? && options[:unix_newlines]
516      File.open(fileName, flag) do |file|
517        file.set_encoding(content.encoding) unless Sass::Util.ruby1_8?
518        file.print(content)
519      end
520    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. For whatever reason, if the file is in a path with spaces it won't work. I moved the folder to a "safe address" and it works like a charm.